# How to add 5th Column in Existing dataFrame Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with consist of 5 columns . I need to add a new column at 3rd Position . How to achieve this in spark .

```
df.show()


+---------+--------+---+----------+--------+
|last_name|position|age|salary_inc| segment|
+---------+--------+---+----------+--------+
|   george|      IT| 10|      2313|     one|
|     jhon|  non-it| 21|     34344|    null|
|     mark|      IT| 11|     16161|   third|
|  spencer|      it| 31|      2322|    null|
|  spencer|  non-it| 41|      2322|Valuable|
+---------+--------+---+----------+--------+


Add new_column at position 3


+---------+--------+-----------+---+----------+--------+
|last_name|position|new_column |age|salary_inc| segment|
+---------+--------+-----------+---+----------+--------+
```

Can you please help me on this

Answer (score 3):

```py
(
  df.withColumn("new_column", ...)
    .select("last_name", 
            "position", 
            "new_column",
             ...)
    .show()
)
```

Where first ellipses indicate what you're creating in your new column called `"new_column"`; for example `lit(1)` would give you literal (constant) 1 of type `IntegerType`. Second ellipses indicate remaining columns in the order you wish to select.

Comment: I think this works perfectly, but we can even avoid using `withColumn` and add the `new_column` directly on the `select`. More if `lit()` function is going to be used on `withColumn`.